# Rest Client with Liferay 7 and OSGI

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, osgi, liferay-7

When I try to deploy my Liferay 7 OSGI component (just a REST client), I get a exception.

```
ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-8][PortletServlet:109] 
  javax.portlet.PortletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: 
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder cannot be found by 
  com.liferay.portal.remote.cxf.common_2.0.6
  javax.portlet.PortletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: 
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder cannot be found by 
  com.liferay.portal.remote.cxf.common_2.0.6
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinPortlet.handleRequest(VaadinPortlet.java:547)
```

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder cannot be found by 
  com.liferay.portal.remote.cxf.common_2.0.6
```

To get this ClientBuilder, I've tried to add the "jersey-min-2.22.2" from the project: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.eclipsesource.jaxrs/jersey-all/2.22.2

So my Question is here: What did I do wrong?

**EDIT: I ansered my own Question.. I forgot to use the JerseyClientBuilder in my Project. Now it works for me.**

Comment: Hi @eddieosi Can you please let me know what exactly you included in the project (file changes) to solve this issue ?